# How can I update a progress display on a Perl command-line application?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, progress-bar

I have a little Perl script (On Windows) that checks some files for me as an aid to my day-to-day business. At the moment it prints out something like...

```
0%
25%
50%
75%
Complete
```

But I can remember scripts I've used in the past that didn't print progress on a line-by-line basis, but which updated the output on the display, presumably by moving the cursor back and over-printing what was there.

Anyone know what magic is required? Portability isn't important to me, the script is quite disposable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, \r will go back to the beginning of the current line

Answer (score 8):

You could use [curses](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI/lib/Curses/UI/Dialog/Progress.pm) and make a nice progress bar.

**EDIT**:
Or do something like this:

```
print "#####                                 [ 10%]\r";
# Do something
print "##########                            [ 20%]\r";
# Do something else
print "###############                       [ 30%]\r";
# Do some more
# ...
# ...
# ...
print "##################################### [100%]\n";
print "Done.\n";
```

Comment: I think on Windows you need to call `binmode(STDOUT)`, before `\r` will work the way you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you ever need to do something in Perl, it's very likely that someone has done it and uploaded it to CPAN. Look at some of the modules with ["progress" in their name](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=progress&mode=all).

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in [Smart Comments](http://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Comments). This would be probably easier than coding Your own progress bars.

Comment: Thank you zoul, that a very smart ;-) module you are recommending here.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to print a backspace character '\b' to move the cursor back so you can overwrite what you printed previously.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works in Perl, but in C/C++ you can use

```
\b
```

for a backspace. Using several of those, you can move the cursor to overwrite old values.