# Printing to same line STDOUT in perl

Tags: perl, console

In perl I want to print status info to STDOUT, but instead of printing line *after* line I want to print the same line. How? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to print a line, and then overwrite it with another line, and then overwrite *that* with another line, and so on?

Comment: Yes. I finally found a solution here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=699555. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Perl: print back to beginning of line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2774596/176646), [How can I update a progress display on a Perl command-line application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/277384/176646), and probably others (already used my close vote).